# How can code User input parameter from first date to last date (SQL query manager)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sapb1

I need help, I write the code and have to use **The Last Date** from user parameter >> [%1] in statement
but when I execute ..the filled window force me fill from the last date to first date. It should be fill from the first date to last date.

when I execute... the "User window" popup and need to input date from the first date to last date (ex:  01/08/20 - 30/09/20)  but from the fact from above coding,

user have to input the last date to the first date (ex: 30/09/20 - 01/08/20) << this will make user confuse
I attached the pic for you can see it clear>>[image: 1]

```
Select 
    T0.docnum , T0.docdate , Sum(T1.Quantity), 
    Sum(case when T0.docdate between dateadd(month,0,DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(day,'[%1]'),'[%1]')) and eomonth(dateadd(month,0,DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(day,'[%1]'),'[%1]'))) then T1.Quantity*T2.U_hmc_vollts else 0 end) as 'm12_Lts'  ,
    sum(case when T0.docdate between dateadd(month,-1,DATEADD(DAY,1- 
    DATEPART(day,'[%1]'),'[%1]')) and eomonth(dateadd(month,-1,DATEADD(DAY,1- 
    DATEPART(day,'[%1]'),'[%1]'))) then T1.Quantity*T2.U_hmc_vollts else 0 end) as 'm11_Lts'
From    OINV T0 
    left join inv1 T1 on T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 
    left join oitm T2 on T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode 
Where 
    T0.docdate >= '[%0]' and T0.Docdate <= '[%1]' 
Group By 
    T0.docnum, T0.Docdate
```

Comment: I'm not clear what the question is, but do you need an `order by` clause?

Comment: I want  ..when I execute the "User window" popup and need to input date from first date to last date (ex:  01/08/20 - 30/09/20)  but from the fact from above coding , 

user have to input last date to first date (ex : 30/09/20 - 01/08/20) << this will make user confuse  (I attached the pic for you can see it clear )  

and I need to use the last date [%1]  in code statement 

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: 'Order by' clause is not what I want

Comment: If you are talking about the order that the user has to input the parameters, thats a function of the SQL Client Interface you are using - so you need to tell us what it is.

Comment: not 'order by' I am talking ...Order is just sort the data but I need User can input from first date to last date and use the last date to be the Variable in calculate code

Comment: Yes, thats what my last comment addressed. Thats why we need to know the user interface you are using.

Comment: but from the code user have to input from the last date to first date on user interface (they input like this >>  30/09/20 - 01/08/20)  this is not naturally inputting the date ,    should be  >> 01/08/20 - 30/09/20
this is sample pic to show you https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEZOO.png

Comment: i write the code in SAP B1 by using Query manager

Comment: This is a question for someone who knows about the SAP B1 Query Manager then - I would suggest consulting the official documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Inserting

```
/*SELECT FROM [dbo].[OWTR] p1*/

declare @FROM as Datetime
declare @TO as datetime
/* WHERE */
set @FROM = /* p1.docdate */ '[%0]'
set @TO = /* p1.docdate */  '[%1]'
```

at the top of your query (the table doesn't really matter)
then replace the [%0] with @FROM and [%1] with @TO in the rest of your query.

Full Code:

```
/*SELECT FROM [dbo].[OWTR] p1*/

 declare @FROM as Datetime
 declare @TO as datetime
 /* WHERE */
 set @FROM = /* p1.docdate */ '[%0]'
 set @TO = /* p1.docdate */  '[%1]'



Select 
T0.docnum , T0.docdate , Sum(T1.Quantity), 
Sum(case when T0.docdate between dateadd(month,0,DATEADD(DAY,1- 
DATEPART(day,@TO),@TO)) and eomonth(dateadd(month,0,DATEADD(DAY,1- 
 DATEPART(day,@TO),@TO))) then T1.Quantity*T2.U_hmc_vollts else 0 end) as 
'm12_Lts'  ,
sum(case when T0.docdate between dateadd(month,-1,DATEADD(DAY,1- 
DATEPART(day,@TO),@TO)) and eomonth(dateadd(month,-1,DATEADD(DAY,1- 
DATEPART(day,@TO),@TO))) then T1.Quantity*T2.U_hmc_vollts else 0 end) as 
'm11_Lts'
From    OINV T0 
left join inv1 T1 on T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 
left join oitm T2 on T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode 
Where 
T0.docdate >= @FROM and T0.Docdate <= @TO 
Group By 
T0.docnum, T0.Docdate
```

let me know how you get on.

Comment: It's work!!  thank you so muchhhh.  
I don't know how to post image to show you the result. but it's work!!  ^o^

Answer (score -1):

Add `order by` to your SQL statement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you for your comment but it's not exact what I want  T_T,

May be my question is not clear ...
hen I execute the "User window" popup and need to input date from first date to last date (ex: 01/08/20 - 30/09/20) but from the fact from above coding , user have to input last date to first date (ex : 30/09/20 - 01/08/20) << this will make user confuse (I attached the pic for you can see it clear ) and I need to use the last date [%1] in code statement Thank you for your help in advance